# How to install an Intel binary file on ARM?

Tags: linux, arm, binary, elf, lsb

I am trying to install a binary file, and I get the output as "`Cannot install binary`".

When I did `file .bin`, the output is:

```
c64plus-imglib_2_02_00_00_Linux-x86_Setup.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped
```

On my ARM machine

```
uname -a:
```

returns

```
Linux overo 3.5.7 #1 PREEMPT Thu Jan 9 16:37:38 CET 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Is there a method to install an Intel binary on an ARM processor?

Comment: I think you need to compile it.

Comment: No, this was compiled for a different architecture, get the source for the package and compile it yourself

Comment: Hi, there is no package source available. Only .bin and .exe. http://www.ti.com/tool/SPRC264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.

A program in binary form can only be executed in a machine with a compatible ISA (Instruction Set Architecture, see [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)). Intel  maintains backward ISA compatibility in each processor generation as a newer ISA is always a superset of older ISA, and a program created for i386 will run on Pentium. However this is not the case between radically different ISAs, like x86-64 and ARM.

Additionally, your installer might be in x86-64 ISA, but the library you are trying to install is compiled in TI 'C64x ISA, a modern architecture from Texas Instruments used at their higher-end DSPs. So, even you use an Intel PC to install the libraries, you cannot copy them to your ARM board and use them, since they are made for that TI architecture.

To make things worse, even if you had the sources of that library, it would be useless for you, since they would most likely be highly optimized for that architecture, using inline calls to assembly code to take advantage of special instructions and exotic hardware resources that only these DSP's may have.

You can try to see if a free and open source image library has the code you are seeking. Begin with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), but you are warned that these big and complex libraries might be a bit difficult to understand.